# Не получается объединить строки в массив

Tags: php

Нужно обьединить массивы с инф о доставки в один 
пробую вот так не выходит

```
$region = "Регион: $dataraw[region]";

$city = "Населенный пункт: $dataraw[city]";

$street = "Улица: $dataraw[street]";

$house = "Дом: $dataraw[house]";

$flat = "Квартира: $dataraw[flat]";

$postal_code = "Индекс: $dataraw[postal_code]";



$adress = array_merge($region, $city, $street, $house, $flat, $postal_code);

echo $adress;
```

Результат пустой экран

Comment: Почитайте про массивы. Вы пытаетесь объединить строки.

Comment: у вас там 6 нотисов в лог пишутся каждый раз при выполнении сего скрипта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваши переменные не массивы, а обычный string.

Для того, чтобы объединить эти значения в массив Вам надо просто изменить **array_merge** на **array**:

```
$region = "Регион: $dataraw[region]";
$city = "Населенный пункт: $dataraw[city]";
$street = "Улица: $dataraw[street]";
$house = "Дом: $dataraw[house]";
$flat = "Квартира: $dataraw[flat]";
$postal_code = "Индекс: $dataraw[postal_code]";

$adress = array($region, $city, $street, $house, $flat, $postal_code);
```

Данный код не покажет значение:

```
echo $adress;
```

Для того, чтобы получить значение, надо написать индекс:

```
echo $adress[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Переменные которые вы пытаетесь объеденить не являются массивами. Поэтому просто используйте:

```
$adress = [$region, $city, $street, $house, $flat, $postal_code];
```

Answer (score 0):

Опишите поля и соответствущие строки заголовков

```
$fields =  ['region' => "Регион", 'city' => "Населенный пункт", ...];
```

и затем собирете данные в результирующий массив.

Вариант с простым циклом:

```
$result = [];
foreach($fields as $f => $title){
    $result[$f] = "$title: ". $dataraw[$f];
}
```

получите нормальный ассоциативный массив с данными.

в случае с определенными переменными `$region, $city` и т.п. ассоциативный массив можно получить через `$result = compact(['region', 'city', ...])`